# Deactivate twoside for bibliography and glossary

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, glossaries, double-sided

since the bibliography and glossary barely fit into their columns and start using several pages, I would like to deactivate twoside for them. 
How can this be acomplished or is that a bad practice?

Comment: do you mean "two-column" or "two-sided"?  both are cited in the tags, and disabling two-column seems to make more sense for material like a glossary or bibliography.  (i'd be very puzzled to see a bibliography crammed into narrow columns, but printed on only one side of a page.)

Answer (score 2):

To get a good typography for printing books or double sided thesis LaTeX starts each new chapter on a right (odd) page.

A bibliography, a glossary, an index have special functions but they are also handeled as chapters of the book. And so the also starts on a right (odd) page.

In my opinion it is important for a good typography **not** to change the kind of printing within an document. I mean, if you choose doublesided typeset the complete document doublesided, if you decide to start a new chapter on the next page (right or left side) do it in the complete document.

**Conclusion:**
The best practice is the inbuild typography of LaTeX for printing double sided documents like books, a thesis, ...